# No Such Payment Method - Clone Payment Method Stripe Connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm following this example to clone a payment method: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods

```
const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.create(
    {
        customer: card.customer,
        payment_method: card.id,
    },
    {
        stripeAccount: vendorAcc,
    }
);
```

This returns:

```
{
  id: 'pm_....',
  object: 'payment_method',
  billing_details: {
    address: {
      city: null,
      country: null,
      line1: null,
      line2: null,
      postal_code: null,
      state: null
    },
    email: '...',
    name: '...',
    phone: null
  },
  card: {
    brand: 'visa',
    checks: {
      address_line1_check: null,
      address_postal_code_check: null,
      cvc_check: 'pass'
    },
    country: 'US',
    exp_month: 3,
    exp_year: ...,
    fingerprint: 'c...',
    funding: 'credit',
    generated_from: null,
    last4: '4242',
    networks: { available: [Array], preferred: null },
    three_d_secure_usage: { supported: true },
    wallet: null
  },
  created: 1616118576,
  customer: null,
  livemode: false,
  metadata: {},
  type: 'card'
}
```

However, when I next try to run:

```
const paymentMethod2 = await stripe.paymentMethods.retrieve(
     paymentMethod.id
);
```

or

```
const paymentMethodAttached = await stripe.paymentMethods.attach(
    paymentMethod.id,
    { customer: card.customer }
```

I get the error:

```
    StripeInvalidRequestError: No such PaymentMethod: 'pm_...'
    ...
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  raw: {
    code: 'resource_missing',
    doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing',
    message: "No such PaymentMethod: 'pm_...'",
    param: 'payment_method',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Fri, 19 Mar 2021 01:49:37 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '262',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
      'access-control-max-age': '300',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      'request-id': 'req_...',
      'stripe-version': '2020-03-02',
      'x-stripe-c-cost': '12',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    statusCode: 404,
    requestId: 'req_...'
  },
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: 'resource_missing',
  doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing',
  param: 'payment_method',
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Fri, 19 Mar 2021 01:49:37 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '262',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'request-id': 'req_...',
    'stripe-version': '2020-03-02',
    'x-stripe-c-cost': '12',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  requestId: 'req_...',
  statusCode: 404,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined
}

    );
```

**UPDATE**:

I am now running:

```
const paymentMethodAttached = await stripe.paymentMethods.attach( 
      paymentMethod.id,
      {
          customer: card.customer,
      },
      {
          stripeAccount: vendorAcc,
      }
);
```

This throws the error:

No such customer: 'cus_...'

When I run

```
const paymentMethod2 = await stripe.paymentMethods.retrieve(
      paymentMethod.id,
      {
         stripeAccount: vendorAcc,
      }
);
```

this returns successfully, with:

```
{
  id: 'pm_...',
  object: 'payment_method',
  billing_details: {
    address: {
      city: null,
      country: null,
      line1: null,
      line2: null,
      postal_code: null,
      state: null
    },
    email: '...',
    name: '...',
    phone: null
  },
  card: {
    brand: 'visa',
    checks: {
      address_line1_check: null,
      address_postal_code_check: null,
      cvc_check: 'pass'
    },
    country: 'US',
    exp_month: 3,
    exp_year: 2024,
    fingerprint: '...',
    funding: 'credit',
    generated_from: null,
    last4: '4242',
    networks: { available: [Array], preferred: null },
    three_d_secure_usage: { supported: true },
    wallet: null
  },
  created: 1616158821,
  customer: null,
  livemode: false,
  metadata: {},
  type: 'card'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

“No such...” errors are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account (e.g. trying to perform an operation from your platform account on an object that was created on a connected account).

In this case it's the second one: your retrieve or attach calls don't [include the Stripe-Account header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header), so they're looking on the wrong Stripe Account.

Update: Also the Customer must exist on the Connected Account, which it likely doesn't given your 'no such Customer' error.